# Did I destroy my monitor by turning on/off a multiple plug/power strip

Tags: power-supply

I tried to make an old windows 7 PC boot into repair mode.

The monitor and the PC were both connected to the same power strip.

I turned it on/off multiple times (hard reset) and now the monitor is dead. 
I had no clue I can kill a device like this...

I am worried now, is the monitor dead or only the power supply of the monitor?

I think there are no "fixes" here, the monitor does not turn on or get any electricity, correct?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH4Bb.jpg) is an image of the power supply.

I tried already two different power strips and a wall plug.

EDIT:

Today I wake up, turn on my laptop and suddenly the monitor works, whats going on here? Did it recover over night? But thats not how tech works, its either broken or not. I am glad that it works now, but I still want to know why.

Also, can turning a [power strip](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/isa/160267/c1/-/en/1345755_BB_00_FB/image.jpg?x=400&y=400) on/off multiple times in a row damage a device? No pause in between, turn on, then immediately off a few times.

Comment: Does the monitor have an external power supply? Have you tried to power it at a wall plug?

Comment: If you have a volt-meter, you may be able to test the output of the power supply pictured to determine whether its output matches its advertised output voltage.  That won't be conclusive, but might be a test you can do before deciding to buy a new monitor.

Comment: In the image, it seems the mains plug is not all the way into the PS. To test the PS, try a light bulb with about the same voltage and less current - a more effective test than a multimeter, which will not draw enough current to be valid. Also check the manufacturer's service manual for an easily-replaceable fuse. A fuse should be less than US$1, and a new multi-purpose PS less than US$10.

Comment: @all thank you for the comments, see the edit please

Comment: Please clarify the time scale: „I turned it on/off multiple times“

Comment: @Daniel B, It happened super fast and after that the monitor was "dead". I used my foot to click the red power strip button. I touched it and the power went of, but the button was not fully pressed, so right after I moved my foot away the power went back on, I noticed and clicked the button again power went off again. To sum it, I pushed the button up 2-3 times without a pause on off on off.

Comment: Well now that is a surefire way to kill just about any sensitive electronic device!

Comment: The monitor might have a [resettable fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse).

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks for this. I think this is the solution. Now I learned something. If you want to answer, I will accept.